# How to call custom proptype function with ES6 React class

Tags: reactjs

How to call a custom proptype function with an ES6 react class ?

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    validate(props, propName, componentName) {
        ...
    );
    ...
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
    children: validate
};
```

I have try many ways (MyComponent.validate, this.validate, with a bind) but nothing works.

Comment: Humm I think the function must be outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to write a custom prop validation for a component, and you want this validation function to be inside the component class.

To call a function in a class without instantiating the class, the function needs to be [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).

This will work:

```js
class SomeClass {
  static func() {
    console.log('in here');
  }
}

SomeClass.func();
```

However, I do not think it is right to keep the validation function for the component in the component class itself. I believe it'd be best to keep that function outside.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I don't really have a good reason. I just haven't seen it used like this anywhere. I think the component class should only deal with rendering the component and managing it's states (the component's 'logic'). This function should be kept outside just like how we always do prop validation outside the class.

Comment: In this case, it's seem impossible to access to a context shared from parental component.

Comment: You can only access the props passed to a component after it has been instantiated. The prop type validation happens before that, so there is no way you can do that. If that is some thing you want to do, this is not the right way to go about it.